# parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given when creating user laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Im building my onw registration in laravel and when im trying to hash my password i get the error **parse_url() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**

//Controller

HomeController.php

```
$filteredValidation = $request->except('_token');
        $password = Hash::make($filteredValidation['password']);
        UserRegistrationRequest::create([
            'firstname' => $filteredValidation['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $filteredValidation['lastname'],
            'email' => $filteredValidation['email'],
            'year' => $filteredValidation['year'],
            'avatar' => $filteredValidation['firstname'],
            'buddy' => $filteredValidation['firstname'],
            'password' => $password,
        ]);
```

//request

UserRegistrationRequest.php

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'year' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

I have no idea why this is happening

Comment: `$password = Hash::make($filteredValidation['password']);` is it correct?

Comment: What is `UserRegistrationRequest`? it's a model? by the name looks like it's a form request...

Comment: I looked at the documentation of laravel wich suggest `'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)` but since im using a validator with the $filteredValidation it should work

Comment: `create` is an Eloquent Model method, but you are trying to use on a FormRequest instance

Comment: If your user model is named `User`, you should `User::create([...]);` instead of `UserRegistrationRequest::create([ ... ]);`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ yeah tried that, now it works, think i have been looking to long at my code that i don't see the small mistakes XD

Comment: Of course, it happens to all of us from time to time. This is the life of the software developer ;-)